# How do you remove elements from an array using methods in a side scroller game?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, methods

I am making a flappy bird game where the player must capture all of the words from an array. Right now, I am using the shift() method to remove elements, as can be seen below:

```
if ( bX + bird.width >= words[i].x 
        && bX + bird.width <= words[i].x + 40
        && bY+bird.height >= words[i].y
        && bY+bird.height <= words[i].y + 40){

        words.shift();
    };
```

For reference, here is the array:

```
var nouns = ["dog", "boy", "house","farm", "phone", "plane", "doctor"];
var words = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {  
    words.push(new word(i * 161 + 200, Math.floor(Math.random() * (400 - 10 + 1)) + 10, nouns[i])); }
```

However, if the player MISSES the first element of the array ("dog") they are then unable to capture any of the remaining elements of the array. How can I fix this so that they player can access the elements of the array in any order?

'
[image: picture here, note shift() only works if the first element of the array (dog) is selected first.]

Answer (score 1):

You are already using the variable `i` in the collision detection. You use it to select the word you are checking.

On the other had you use `words.shift()` which always removes the *first* word of the array.

This might work as long as your bird is always at the far left and all words have a reasonable distance on the x axis.

But if you want to do it more generally, you could test all possible words in a loop and remove all that are hit or went out of screen.

There are multiple ways to remove an item from an array. For example you can use `words.splice(i, 1)` to remove `words[i]`. If you're using this in a look, keep in mind that all subsequent indexes changed by 1.

```
for (let i = 0; i < words.length; ++i) {
    if (birdCollidesWithWord(words[i]) || wordWentOutOfScreen(words[i])) {
        words.splice(i, 1);
        i -= 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (words[i].x <= 0){
        words.shift();

    }
```

I entered this code in before my collision detection code. It allowed the first element of the array to be missed and simply shifted that element, thereby removing the first element of the array and allowing the player to continue collecting the other elements.